# Need preview page before send email

Tags: javascript, php, sendmail, preview

My email sending script send email after submitting the form.Form data are directly sent to receiver email address after clicking submit button, but I need preview page which will show preview of form data before sending email. Here form action is controlled by javascript file workMail.js and action page is sendMail.php

Thanks for any help.

Here is my code

**index.php**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
<title></title>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<meta content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no" name="viewport">
<script src="http://unnayannews.com/testjs/jquery_003.js"></script>

<script src="js/workMail.js"></script>

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/mailAlert.css">

</head>
<body style="margin: 0px;">

            <div class="onedari_form_wrapper info_form_wrapper ajast_onedari_form mgt0">
                <form id="contactForm">
                    <div class="form_field">
                        <label id="name">■Name<span class="red">*</span></label>

                        <input kl_virtual_keyboard_secure_input="on" placeholder="Name" class="custom_input" name="name" type="text" required>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form_field">
                        <label id="mail">■Email<span class="red">*</span></label>
                        <input kl_virtual_keyboard_secure_input="on"  class="custom_input" name="mail" type="text" required>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form_field">
                        <label id="age">■Age<span class="red">*</span></label><br>
                        <input kl_virtual_keyboard_secure_input="on" style="width: 30%" placeholder="" class="custom_input" name="age" type="text" required>
                    </div>
                    <p style="margin: 0px 0px 8px;"><label id="work">■Work<span class="red">*</span></label></p>

 <div class="category-wrapper">


 <input  id="CategoryCategory10" class="checkbox" value="10" name="data[]" type="checkbox" >
 <label for="CategoryCategory10">App development</label>
  <br>                                          <input  id="CategoryCategory209" class="checkbox" value="209" name="data[]" type="checkbox"> <label for="CategoryCategory209">System management</label>
          <br>                           
                                            <input  id="CategoryCategory213" class="checkbox" value="213" name="data[]" type="checkbox"> <label for="CategoryCategory213">Web</label><br>
                                            <input id="CategoryCategory19" class="checkbox" value="19" name="data[]" type="checkbox"> <label for="CategoryCategory19">Graphics</label><br>

                <br>

                    <button id="send" class="submit bg_red" type="button" name="send">Submit</button>

                </form>
            </div>
</body>
</html>
```

**sendMail.php**

```
<?php


if( isset($_POST['data']) && is_array($_POST['data']) ) {
    foreach($_POST['data'] as $data) {   }
    $datatList = implode(', ', $_POST['data']);
}
$send_for_address = "test@email.com";
$header = "From: test@email.com";
 $messages = "Name: $_POST[name]\n";
 $messages .= "Email: $_POST[mail]\n";
 $messages .= "Age : $_POST[age]\n";
 $messages .= "Work $datatList\n";  

mail($send_for_address, $messages,$header);

        mb_internal_encoding("UTF-8");
if (mail($send_for_address, $messages,$header)) {

        $response = <<<HTML
<div class='alert'>
    <div class='alert-header'><div class="alert-remove layerOff">×</div></div>
    <div class="alert-body fs0_7">
        Thank you for your applicaion!
    </div>
    <div class="alert-footer">
        <input type="button" value="OK" class="layerOff">
    </div>
</div>
HTML;
        echo json_encode(array("success"=>true, "message"=> $response));
        }else{}

?>
```

**workMail.js**

```
$(function(){
    // sendForm
    $("#send").on("click", function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        chackError("#contactForm");
    });

    $(document).on("click", ".layerOff", function(){
        $(".overlay").remove();
    });
});


function chackError(selector){
    var $form = $(selector);
    var name = $form.find("input[name='name']").val();
    var mail = $form.find("input[name='mail']").val();
    var age = $form.find("input[name='age']").val();
    /*var work = $form.find("textarea[name='work']").val();*/

    var dataval =  document.getElementsByName("data[]"); 
             // or document.querySelectorAll('[name="summer[]"]');

var checked = [].filter.call( dataval , function( v ){
    return v.checked;
});



    $form.find(".coution").remove();
    var error_frag = false;


    if ( checked.length < 1 ) {
  $("#work").append("<span class='coution'><br>Work field reqire</span>");
        error_frag = true;
        error_kind = "#work";       
}

    if(age == ""){
        $("#age").append("<span class='coution'><br>Age field reqire</span>");
        error_frag = true;
        error_kind = "#age";
    }
    if(mail == ""){
        $("#mail").append("<span class='coution'><br>email field reqire</span>");
        error_frag = true;
        error_kind = "#mail";
    }
    if(name == ""){
        $("#name").append("<span class='coution'><br>Name field reqire</span>");
        error_frag = true;
        error_kind = "#name";
    }
    if(error_frag === false){
        sendForm();
    }else{
        var targetY = $(error_kind).offset().top;
        var headerH = $("#header").height();
        var ajast = ($(window).width() >= 761)? 80 : 20;
        $("html, body").animate({ scrollTop: targetY - headerH - ajast}, 'fast');
    }
}

function sendForm(){
    var post_data = $("#contactForm").serialize();
    $("#contactForm").find("input, checkbox, textarea").val("").end().find(":checked").prop("checked", false);
    $.post("sendMail.php",
        post_data,
        function(data){
            if(data.success === false){
                alert("error");
                $(".overlay").remove();
            }else{
                $("body").append("<div class='overlay'></div>");
                $(".overlay").html(data.message);
                $("html, body").animate({ scrollTop: 0}, 'fast');
         }
        },
        "json"
    );
    return false;
}
```

Comment: Since you are using an ajax solution, why not break your `sendMail.php` into 2 parts, one that displays the data for preview with hidden form inputs and confirm button, then when hit confirm it calls itself again but with a new check variable that uses the code you currently have?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Further to my comment, what I mean by splitting up the `sendMail.php` (you will, of course, have to modify your main page javascript to accommodate a confirm response from your `sendMail.php`):

```
if(isset($_POST['data']) && is_array($_POST['data']) ) {
        foreach($_POST['data'] as $data) {   }
        $datatList = implode(', ', $_POST['data']);
    }
else
    $datatList  =   $_POST['data'];


if(!isset($_POST['confirm'])) {

        $name       =   strip_tags($_POST['name']);
        $email      =   strip_tags($_POST['mail']);
        $age        =   preg_replace('/[^0-9]/','',$_POST['age']);
        $data       =   strip_tags($datatList);
        $response   =   '
    <h2>Preview</h2>
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td>NAME:</td><td>'.$name.'</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>EMAIL:</td><td>'.$email.'</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>AGE:</td><td>'.$age.'</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>DATA:</td><td>'.$data.'</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="2">
                <form id="confirm" method="post" action="">
                    <input type="hidden" name="name" value="'.$name.'" />
                    <input type="hidden" name="mail" value="'.$email.'" />
                    <input type="hidden" name="age" value="'.$age.'" />
                    <input type="hidden" name="data" value="'.$data.'" />
                    <input type="submit" name="confirm" value="Confirm" />
                </form>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>';
        echo json_encode(array("confirm"=>true, "message"=> $response));
    }
else {
        $send_for_address   = "test@email.com";
        $header             = "From: test@email.com";
        $messages           = "Name: $_POST[name]\n";
        $messages           .= "Email: $_POST[mail]\n";
        $messages           .= "Age : $_POST[age]\n";
        $messages           .= "Work $datatList\n";  
        mail($send_for_address, $messages,$header);
        mb_internal_encoding("UTF-8");
        if (mail($send_for_address, $messages,$header)) {
                $response = <<<HTML
<div class='alert'>
    <div class='alert-header'><div class="alert-remove layerOff">×</div></div>
    <div class="alert-body fs0_7">
        Thank you for your applicaion!
    </div>
    <div class="alert-footer">
        <input type="button" value="OK" class="layerOff">
    </div>
</div>
HTML;
                echo json_encode(array("success"=>true, "message"=> $response));
            }
    }
```

Comment: Thank you for your help, it is showing form data at preview in pop up, but problem is it is not sending email and showing thank you message after clicking confirm button.

Comment: That is the part I mentioned about you modifying your javascript to accommodate the confirm page. You just use the same javascript to resubmit the form with the `confirm` field and it will resubmit the form to the same page but this time bypass the confirm page and run the second half of that submit script.